# ui-router renders template before state changes

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a nested state structure like this:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: ...
            controller: mainController,
            resolve: {
                Resolve1: ...
                Resolve2: ...
            }
        })
        .state('main.state1', {
            url: '^/state1/:id/',
            templateUrl: ....
            controller: state1Controller,
            resolve: {
                Resolve11: ...
                Resolve22: ...
            },
        })
        .state('main.state2', {
        ....
```

From what I am seeing, when you are at state `main.state1` and you navigate to the same state with another `id` parameter, the template for `main.state1` is rendered fine but the template for `main` (the parent) is rendered before the state changes (I guess it doesn't wait for the data resolution of `main.state1`). This results to the view being rendered with the wrong data (more specifically, the state parameters that I use for generating links are wrong).

My `mainController` has the `$stateParams` and `$state` injected to it and that's where I get the data from.

Did anyone notice this before? Is this by design or is it a bug?

Is there any way to update the parent view with the latest data?

However, I would expect ui-router to wait for all data resolutions until it starts rendering the views (even the parent). I don't know if I am missing something here, but this is my understanding of the problem so far...

**UPDATE:**

I see now that a function that is involved in the view rendering (with interpolation) gets called many times, first with the old values and then with the new values. But the final result that I see on screen is using the initial data that were used when I first entered the 'main.*' state. This is SO weird.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have found that my links where not updated ONLY when using ui-sref (note that I was using parameters in the state href, e.g. ui-sref="main.state1({id:{{getId()}}})"). When switched to ng-href everything worked as expected.

I have no idea why, but that fixed the problem.

The odd thing was that the ui-sref was evaluated, but the link was not updated.

Go figure...

**UPDATE 3:**

This solution in turn caused other problems. Then the first click reloaded the application... So this is not the best fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "solution" was to use `ng-click` with `$state.go()`, instead of links.

This appears to be a bug in ui-router.

Answer (score 0):

ui-router transitions "through" the parent state to the child. That means main will be triggered, then main.state1. I ran into this myself where I was getting duplicate listeners and HTML DOM elements - main is actually running AT THE SAME TIME as main.state1. This behavior is by design, and AFAIK your only option is to design around it.